# is it possible to pass through command-line options to a script in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an RSpec script that tests a program in a different language I am developing. Since I can run and test 32 and 64-bit versions of this application, I would like to have a way to signal this on the command-line.

What I really want is to do something like this:

`rspec -c myspec.rb lin32`

or

`rspec -c myspec.rb lin64`

and have the lin32 or lin64 be passed as a string I can access in the ruby file itself. Is this possible? [This site](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203473) mentions environment variables but that is cumbersome. It also mentioned doing ARGV manipulation -- is this a possible way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From David Chelimsky

You can't pass arbitrary arguments to the rspec command, but you can set an environment variable like this:

```
SLEEP=10 rspec test.rb
```

Then within the script, the value of `ENV["SLEEP"]` is `"10"`, so you can say:

```
sleep(ENV["SLEEP"].to_f)
```

Comment: This works only on linux/unix. However, windows is not allowing to pass the argument like that

Answer (score 0):

Try the `--` parameter. It's used to tell an app to stop processing parameters and pass the remaining ones to a child process. I don't know if rspec understands it but it's worth a try.

```
`rspec -c myspec.rb -- lin32`
`rspec -c myspec.rb -- lin64`
```